# Hand rig not rotating with IK bone

Tags: modeling, rigging

Rotating the hand IK only rotates the base hand bone, not any of the parented finger bones. Below is my best attempt at showing what I mean.

It may be worth noting that I parented the IK bone to the *hand*, rather than the conventional *wrist*, since I have unconventional movement in that bone.

[Blend file here, I think.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aw__SEDepHDdsVgihtnSTIIQ_K6o0ArM/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Fig 1]

[image: Fig 2]

Comment: without seeing your settings we can just guess around so i would recommend providing your blend file. thx.

Comment: @Chris Done, thanks.

Comment: File link shows "access denied".

Comment: Ffs. It should work now.

Comment: It doesn't rotate any of the fingers because none of the fingers are parented to the hand bone.  They're parented to the wrist bone instead, but the wrist isn't copying rotation, the hand is.  If you want the fingers to follow the rotation of the hand bone, parent their chains to the hand bone.

Comment: You’re *kidding*. That’s the oldest mistake in the book. Nonetheless, thanks.